# Hide an anchor on index only

Tags: jquery, html

I'd like to hide an anchor on my index file and have it appear on all interior pages using .attr(), but I can't figure it out.  It remains hidden on all of my pages.  The script and html are below.  Thanks in advance.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    if($('a.logo').attr('href') == 'index.php') {
        $('.logo').hide();
    }
});
```

```html
<div class="page-header large-3 small-12 columns">
    <a href="index.php" class="logo svg-shadow"></a>
</div>
```

Comment: add the script in file where you don't want it to appear.

Comment: "all interior pages" What is that?

Comment: Look, if this HTML is the same on every page, why do you expect your JS to give a different result on some pages? The `href` attribute of `a.logo` seems to always be `index.php`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are testing if the link links to the index page, not if you are *on* the index page.

Possibly you want:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    if(location.pathname === "/" || location.pathname === "/index.php") {
        $('.logo').hide();
    }
});
```

Comment: +1, of course, but the pedant in me wants to see `.toLowerCase()` in there.

Answer (score -1):

Are you using vanilla PHP or are you using a framework? If you want the link to not appear on your index and appear on all subsequent pages, I would put it in a partial code segment that gets rendered on each page you want to display the link. If it's a header item, I would include it in the header and then render the header on every page. It's a little hard to figure out the best way to go about this without a little more context.

In staying with jQuery, I would do the following

```
var pathname = $(location).attr('href');

if(pathname == "http://example.com/index.php") {
  // Don't render the link
}
else {
  // Render the link
}
```

The problem with this approach is you're adding a jQuery check on *each page* to check for a url. This is not the most efficient way to do this. If you're not using a framework, I would just add the link in the pages you want the link to appear, and remove it from the other pages, such as `index.php`

Comment: `location.pathname` is what you should be using, and you shouldn't wrap javascript objects with jQuery so you can get attributes.  You just get them by name - `location.href`